# Drag and drop and insert into MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, draggable

This is my first question here. Long story short, I want to do this:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#sortable

But, when I drag the "drag me down" box to the sortable list below, I want it to add a row to my MySQL table using PHP. I could achieve part of what I want like this:

http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2009/09/shopping-cart-php-jquery/demo.php

But I want the user to be able to sort as in the jqueryui demo.

In the jqueryui demo, where "drag me down" sits in the above example, there would be a list of choices. The list would be the result of a query to a MySQL table. Where item 1, 2, 3 are in the jqueryui example, it would be blank until the user dragged their desired list items into the item 1/2/3 area, which should be sortable (i.e. be able to drag the list items around in the list and create the desired order).

So, how do I insert into the database when a new list item is dragged into the item 1/2/3 area. I know how to achieve the sorting. But I have no idea how to actually add items to a list to be able to sort them. And Google searches have turned up nothing useful.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite understanding what you are asking here.

> *But I have no idea how to actually add items to a list to be able to sort them*

If you have achieved what is in the jQuery UI Demo then I expect you are looking at how to serialize the users modifications and send modifications to the server in-order to update the database.

If so then you may want to look at the sortable method [serialize](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#method-serialize) which serializes the lists id in order to send as an Ajax request.

```
.sortable( "serialize" , [options] )
```

There is also the [change](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#event-change) event that you can hook into when the user has changed the sort.

```
$( ".selector" ).bind( "sortchange", function(event, ui) {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Start off small and get javascript / jquery to set off an `alert()` or `console.log()` when 'the user dragged their desired list items into the item'. Then replace that `alert()` or `console.log()` with a ajax request.